# Using count and for_each together to create AKS additional node pool by terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

Terraform snippet below to accomplish 0/1/2 additional node pools,

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aksnp" {
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      node_count
    ]
  }
  count                 = local.additional_node_pool_required == "true" ? 1 : 0
  for_each              = var.additional_node_pools
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.id
  name                  = each.value.node_os == "Windows" ? substr(each.key, 0, 6) : substr(each.key, 0, 12)
  node_count            = each.value.node_count
  vm_size               = each.value.vm_size
  availability_zones    = each.value.zones
  max_pods              = each.value.max_pods
  os_disk_size_gb       = each.value.os_disk_size_gb
  os_type               = each.value.node_os
  vnet_subnet_id        = var.vnet_subnet_id
  node_taints           = each.value.taints
  enable_auto_scaling   = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling
  min_count             = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling_min_count
  max_count             = each.value.cluster_auto_scaling_max_count
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. It throws the obvious error like below,

```
The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of "count" and "for_each"
│
│   on main.tf line 99, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "aksnp":
│   99:   for_each              = var.additional_node_pools
│
│ The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only one should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be created.
```

I need some guidance and help from you as I am baffled how do I create node pools with settings?

I need for_each as I want customers to be provided with an option to create as much as additional node pools as they want.

I do also have a requirement that some business users may not request an additional node pool.

How do we solve both problems?

Is there not an easy way to do it in Terraform?

P. S: How do I set the value from Parent Module (local_additional_pools_required) to false? as I want parent module to instruct the child module (AKS) if additional node pools are to be created or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `for_each` to create conditional resources as well:

```
for_each              = local.additional_node_pool_required == "true" ? var.additional_node_pools : {}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin! Shall test it out today and let you know.

Comment: @learner No problem. Let me know how it will go:-)

Comment: Marcin a quick question in parent module when I do not want to create an additional node pool I set variable additional_node_pool_required = false? But locals are internal to module not external? Kindly shed some light please.

Comment: @learner Not sure what do you mean? But I guess you want to access locals of parent from a child module? Then you are correct, you can't do that.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I have updated my question with P.S Section. Kindly provide me some guidance. Many Thanks!

Comment: @learner I would suggest making new question for that. This way more ppl would be able to see it and provide their help as well.